# iTunes COM/AppleScript - podcast RSS

Tags: com, rss, applescript, itunes

I need to get a list of the RSS subscriptions from iTunes.  I'm using the COM interface that Apple provides for controlling iTunes, and have tried this both on Windows and Mac.

e.g.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with a_track in tracks of playlist "Podcasts"
        get artist of a_track
        get album of a_track
        get name of a_track
        get rating of a_track
    end repeat
end tell
```

I can get a list of the podcast episodes, but not their corresponding RSS URLs.  iTunes seems to put all the episodes as tracks in the "Podcasts" playlist, but there doesn't seem to be any kind of grouping as you would expect from what is shown in the window.

Comment: Looking at this code you can see how the grouping can be donehttp://tinyurl.com/9wp5s5 as for getting the feed url - I looked around in the AppleScript Library and searching for RSS, Feed, url didn't give any related answers. So I think that can't be done. It is possible to update podcasts in code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like iTunes does not make this information available (if it even uses RSS feeds to handle podcasts). There's no URL exposed via AppleScript, or stored in the ID3 tags or iTunes Music Library XML document.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a poke around iTunes before trying to find the same info.

I've not managed to find the URLs for the actual podcast feeds, either, but you can get the URL for tracks that haven't been downloaded yet under the **address** attribute.

If the track has been downloaded to disk, the track won't have an **address** attribute, but will have an alias to the file under its **location** attribute.